# How can we convert from <a>fai</a><b>3</b> to <fai>3</fai> using xpath in WSO2 ESB

Tags: json, xpath, wso2, wso2-esb

I am getting JSON like this

```
{"request":""AttributesCriteriaList":[
            {"FieldName":"PartyBranchId","OperationType":1,"FieldValue":"-1500000000","JoinType":2},
            {"FieldName":"AssetTypeId","OperationType":1,"FieldValue":"-1500000001","JoinType":2},
            {"FieldName":"PeriodFrom","OperationType":10,"FieldValue":"1356998400","JoinType":2},
            {"FieldName":"PeriodTo","OperationType":11,"FieldValue":"1358208000","JoinType":2},
            {"FieldName":"Status","OperationType":1,"FieldValue":"4","JoinType":2}
            ]
}
```

How can I convert in to

```
{"assetid":"150000001","partybranchid":"152555222"}
```

in WSO2 ESB?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to translate the given message using XSLT (If you aware of writing XSLT this seems pretty simple)
   Then you just required to write a a proxy (in WSO2 ESB),

```
 <proxy name="JSONTOJSONTranformProxy" transports="https,http">
  <target>
  <inSequence>
     <xslt key="translate.xslt"/>
     <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
     <send>
        <address ="[SOME_ADDRESS]"/>
     </send>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <send/>
  </outSequence>
  </target>
 </proxy>
```

Comment: Actually i need to pass above value to my dynamic query to retrive the data..my query is like: select * from emp where e_no=? or e_name=? or e_sal=?; i will get only one parameter based on criteria how can i pass it to database in wso2 esb i had used dss but its not working its unable to handle a integer type casting now i am trying in dblookup mediator..thanks